# Using strsplit() in R, ignoring anything in parentheses

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I'm trying to use `strsplit()` in R to break a string into pieces based on commas, but I don't want to split up anything in parentheses. I think the answer is a regex but I'm struggling to get the code right.

So for example:

```
x <- "This is it, isn't it (well, yes)"
> strsplit(x, ", ")
[[1]]
[1] "This is it"     "isn't it (well" "yes)"
```

When what I would like is:

```
[1] "This is it"     "isn't it (well, yes)"
```

Comment: You try to use the braces `(...)` as a non splitable block scope and have to put your intention into the splitting regexp. This is not a simple task.

Answer (score 15):

We can use `PCRE` regex to `FAIL` any `,` that follows that a `(` before the `)` and split by `,` followed by 0 or more space (`\\s*`)

```
 strsplit(x, '\\([^)]+,(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,\\s*', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
 #[1] "This is it"           "isn't it (well, yes)"
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest another regex with `(*SKIP)(*F)` to ignore all the `(...)` substrings and only match the commas outside of parenthesized substrings:

```
x <- "This is it, isn't it (well, yes), and (well, this, that, and this, too)"
strsplit(x, "\\([^()]*\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\\h*,\\h*", perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/bD58S5)

You can read more about [*How do (*SKIP) or (*F) work on regex?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/3832970) here. The regex matches:

- `\(` - an opening bracket
- `[^()]*` - zero or more characters other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a closing bracket
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - the verbs that advance the current regex index to the position after the closing bracket
- `|` - or...
- `\\h*,\\h*` - a comma surrounded with zero or more horizontal whitespaces.

Comment: Did you hijack *stribizhev*'s account? o_O

Comment: @BhargavRao: It is my account, I just changed the name. You can do it once a month on SO :)

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

Adding on to @Wiktor's sample string,

```
x <- "This is it, isn't it (well, yes), and (well, this, that, and this, too). Let's look, does it work?"
```

Now the magic:

```
> strsplit(x, ", |(?>\\(.*?\\).*?\\K(, |$))", perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "This is it"                                       
[2] "isn't it (well, yes)"                             
[3] "and (well, this, that, and this, too). Let's look"
[4] "does it work?"
```

So how does `, |(?>\\(.*?\\).*?\\K(, |$))` match?

- `|` captures either of the groups on either side, both

  - on the left, the string `,`
  - and on the right, `(?>\\(.*?\\).*?\\K(, |$))`:

    - `(?> ... )` sets up [an atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), which does not allow backtracking to reevaluate what it matches.
    - In this case, it looks for an open parenthesis (`\\(`),
    - then any character (`.`) repeated from 0 to infinity times (`*`), but as few as possible (`?`), i.e. `.` is evaluated lazily.
    - The previous `.` repetition is then limited by the first close parenthesis (`\\)`),
    - followed by another set of any character repeated 0 to as few as possible (`.*?`)
    - with [a `\\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) at the end, which throws away the match so far and sets the starting point of a new match.
    - The previous `.*?` is limited by a capturing group (`( ... )`) with an `|` that either

      - selects an actual text string, `,`,
      - or moves `\\K` to the end of the line, `$`, if there are no more commas.

*Whew.*

If my explanation is confusing, see the docs linked above, and check out [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), where you can put in the above regex (single escaped—`\`—instead of R-style double escaped—`\\`) and a test string to see what it matches and get an explanation of what it's doing. You'll need to set the `g` (global) modifier in the box next to the regex box to show all matches and not just the first.

Happy `strsplit`ing!

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!