# Split string by space except what's inside parentheses

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I have the following string:

```
x <- "(((K05708+K05709+K05710+K00529) K05711),K05712) K05713 K05714 K02554"
# [1] "(((K05708+K05709+K05710+K00529) K05711),K05712) K05713 K05714 K02554"
```

and I want to split it by space delimiter avoiding what's inside the parentheses in order to have something like:

```
[[1]]
[1] "(((K05708+K05709+K05710 K00529) K05711),K05712)"                
[2] "K05713"                          "K05714"                         
[4] "K02554"
```

See that two spaces remain inside the first parentheses level.

I read the following answers but I couldn't make it work in my case:
[r split on delimiter not in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940561/r-split-on-delimiter-not-in-parentheses) and
[Using strsplit() in R, ignoring anything in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347537/using-strsplit-in-r-ignoring-anything-in-parentheses)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like your string has nested balanced `()`, and you need to skip those spaces inside *balanced* parentheses, right?

Comment: Yes! You are correct.

Comment: Does the last parenthesis on each line always mark the end of the first field?  Are the number of fields known (here 4)?

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: no they aren't. It's just an example of many possibilities. I'm not following you on the first one, are you asking if all the cases I have follow the same pattern of being the first field the nested one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a regex matching the balanced parentheses and then skipping them, and then matching the whitespaces that remain with the following PCRE-based regex:

```
(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|\s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fbEfjU/1) (replace the space with `\s` above for better visibility).

**Pattern details**:

- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)` - Group 1 matching

  - `\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\)` - a substring presenting a balanced parentheses substring: `\(` matches a `(`, `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` matches zero or more (`*`) sequences of 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` (see `[^()]++`) or the whole pattern of this whole Group 1 (see the subrouting call `(?1)`), then `\)` matches a literal `)` and `(*SKIP)(*F)` make the regex discard the whole matched text while keeping the regex index at the end of that match, and proceed looking for the next match
- `|` - or
- - a space to split against

Here is an [online R demo](http://ideone.com/yg5Udw):

```
s <- "(((K05708+K05709+K05710+K00529) K05711),K05712) K05713 K05714 K02554"
strsplit(s, "(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))(*SKIP)(*F)| ", perl=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "(((K05708+K05709+K05710+K00529) K05711),K05712)"
[2] "K05713"                                         
[3] "K05714"                                         
[4] "K02554"
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work fine. Could you explain a little the regex you used?

Comment: Please check my answer. If the explanation is not enough, see also [Regex Recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) and [Subroutines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html). Also, see [How do (*SKIP) or (*F) work on regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex).